# Tensor flow LSTM for speech recognition slows down when training each subsequent word

Tags: python, speech-recognition, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

so I am trying to use tensorflows LSTM to recognise spoken words. However, after each training word is passed through the LSTM the next word takes longer to process (specifically the calculation of gradient by back propogation and the application of these to the network). I am currently working on an iMac without CUDA support so I am having to use a CPU not a GPU (I will be switching to GPU once I am able to).

I am programming using Python-2.7

I am using a very small vocabulary, 8 word classes with 10 training examples of each and each word is isolated (is not part of a sentence, just a word on its own).

Each word is preprocessed into Mel Frequency Cepstral coefficients and then these are clustered using Kmeans with K = 100. So the input to the LSTM is a list of float32s fed in one item at a time.

The slowdown is definitely occurring in the LSTM as the time taken to fetch each item from the list and pass it to the LSTM is staying roughly the same for each item. The size of each item passed to the LSTM is also the same each time (longer words simply have longer lists of items); however, even shorter words (with less items in their list) are still taking progressively longer as the training continues.

I am using gradient decent and backpropogation to train the network and have tried clipping gradients to 10 time steps or not clipping at all, which makes no difference.

The LSTM is instantiated with:

```
 cell = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(size, forget_bias=config.forget_bias)
 cell_layers = rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([cell] * config.num_layers) 
 //pass inputs through the cell
 outputs, states = RNN.rnn(cell_layers, _inputs,initial_state=self._initial_state)
```

After the LSTM I have a softmax layer; the output of which is compared to a one hot vector which represents the correct output, using cross enthalpy loss.

Pipeline sudo code:

```
_inputs = [[float32]*]
for input in _inputs: //input = _inputs[0][0] at time zero input = _inputs[0][1] at time 1 etc.
lstm_output = LSTM(input)
soft_out = softmax(last_output)
cost = CrossEnthalpyCost(soft_out, answer)
gradients = backprop(cost)
new_weights = gradientDecent(gradients, learning_rate)
```

Finally, in case I haven't been clear about what my problem is, here is the timings from my network:

```
Epoch: 0 Learning rate: 1.000
{'heart': 5, 'car': 1, 'dog': 3, 'cat': 2, 'book': 0, 'three': 7,   'girl': 4, 'milk': 6}
book

time to input all clusters for one word into network: 0.0293724536896
time to pass all inputs for one word and perform gradient decent:2.956
Time difference from previous word: 2.956
Epoch Number: 0 Word Number:1, Number of Pieces:247, Word ID:0

time to input all clusters for one word into network: 0.0287952423096
time to pass all inputs for one word and perform gradient decent:3.738
Time difference from previous word: 0.782
Epoch Number: 0 Word Number:2, Number of Pieces:247, Word ID:0

time to input all clusters for one word into network: 0.029797077179
time to pass all inputs for one word and perform gradient decent:4.754
Time difference from previous word: 1.015
Epoch Number: 0 Word Number:3, Number of Pieces:250, Word ID:0
...

time to input all clusters for one word into network: 0.0417804718018
time to pass all inputs for one word and perform gradient decent:25.123
Time difference from previous word: 12.255
Epoch Number: 0 Word Number:24, Number of Pieces:258, Word ID:2
...

time to input all clusters for one word into network: 0.0413291454315
time to pass all inputs for one word and perform gradient decent:40.364
Time difference from previous word: 0.932
Epoch Number: 0 Word Number:38, Number of Pieces:255, Word ID:3
```

If anyone has any ideas as to why it's taking longer and longer

Comment: Are you calling the LSTM construction code multiple times (e.g. after each call to `sess.run()`)?  That would cause execution times to grow, as TensorFlow is optimized for when you reuse the same graph multiple times.

Comment: @mrry The LSTM is created at the start of the session using a with statement.
i.e. `with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as session:`
I do use `session.run(tf.assign(some_variable, some_other_variable))` to assign various different variables which change throughout the session. For example, I have a flag which tells the optimiser when the end of a word has been reached so it should calculate the cost. 
That happens once per word so I can't see how that would increase the processing time for each subsequent word.

Thanks.

Comment: That all sounds sensible. We might need to see your training loop to get an idea why this could be happening.

Comment: `with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as session:
        initialiser = tf.random_normal_initializer(config.mean, config.std)`
        `with tf.variable_scope("model",reuse=None, initializer=initialiser):
                 m = ASR_model(session, config, check, training=True)`
        `tf.initialize_all_variables().run()`
        `for i in range(config.decay_epoch):
                train_accuracy, train_cost = run_epoch(session, m, vocab, train_data, m.opt_out, config, i, training=True)`

Comment: `def run_epoch(session, m, vocab, data, optimiser, config, epoch_number, training=False):
    state = m.initial_state.eval()   
    for (inputs, answer, w_nd_flg, pieces) in ASR.iterate_data(data, config, vocab, epoch_number):
        session.run(tf.assign(m.word_end_flag, w_nd_flg))
        
        cost, state, _, soft_out, accuracy = session.run([m.cost, m.final_state, m.opt_out, m.soft_out, m.accuracy],
                                     {m.input: inputs,
                                      m.answers: answer,
                                      m.initial_state: state})`

Comment: Sorry about the formatting on that code, I'm new to the website and can't figure out how to get it to keep its formatting when I copy and paste it.

Comment: @mrry, are my previous comments the information you wanted me to provide?

Comment: Part of the problem might be the `tf.assign()` in the training loop: this adds a new node to the graph each time you run it, and there might be an O(N) component that comes to dominate due to the graph growing in each iteration. It may also add constants to the graph from `w_nd_flag` in each iteration. You should rewrite it so that you call `tf.assign()` just once  (with a placeholder argument) when you build the graph and feed the appropriate values in the call to `session.run()`.

Comment: @mrry Thank you so much! Removing the tf.assig, changing word_end_flag to a placeholder and using the feed_dict has fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was caused by a using tf.assign each time a word segment was fed in. This causes the graph to grow as a new variable is created each time. In my case, each word was broken into around 250 pieces hence the rapid and large increase in time taken.

The issue was solved by removing the tf.assign method and replacing the offending variable with a placeholder which is set using the feed_dict not tf.assign.

Thanks to @mrry for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

A nice trick to help with this kind of bug is `Graph.finalize()`... once you have added all the graph ops you intended to, call finalize and any attempts to add additional ops to the graph will throw an error. Was very helpful to me when I started and hadn't fully internalized the "I build the graph ONCE and get pointers to tensors as I do, then I exclusively run ops/call eval on the tensors to do stuff" mantra